¿Como puedo extraer el numero de una variable string en C#?
Tengo este listBox con unos datos que recibo de un checador y lo que quiero es básicamente separar el número y la fecha, se me ocurre que puedo tomar las variables con la separación que tengo ahí (esta "|"), he buscado si existe alguna función, pero tal parece no existe algo como tal para C# (o por lo menos yo no la encontré), digo de tal forma que yo pueda tener acceso a las dos variables.


En la mayoría de los lenguajes de programación existe .split()

Lo lógico seria tomar la cadena y leerla hasta que encuentres el símbolo OR ("|") , ya luego parseas el resultado a entero. Puedes leer la documentacion sobre como implementar el método split()

Puedes iterar cada valor que tiene los datos del checador y usar Split() para obtener el código y la fecha, por ejemplo:
string[] valores = datoChecador.Split('|');
string valorCodigo = "";
string valorCodigo = "";

if (valores.Length >= 2)
{
    valorCodigo = valores[0].Trim(); 
    valorFecha = valores[1].Trim();        
}

puedes realizar lo mismo usando lambda como otra opción:
  using System;
  using System.Linq;
  ...
  ...
  ... 
  var resultados = datoChecador.Split('|').Select(valor =>
    {
        if (valor.Contains('|'))
        {
            string[] valores = valor.Split('|');
            return new { valorCodigo = valores[0], valorFecha = valores[1] };
        }
        else
        {
            return new { valorCodigo = valor, valorFecha  = "" };
        }
    });

    foreach (var item in resultados)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"valorCodigo:{item.valorCodigo}, valorFecha:{item.valorFecha}");
    }


se podria acortar con un lambda, pero, el resultado es el mismo y es mas comprensible como lo pones, ojalá le sirva

Gracias me funciono :D
